# Why does command prompt open and close immediately when i open netbeans ide?

Tags: java, netbeans, command-prompt

Why does command prompt open and close immediately when i open netbeans ide ?Although i do not want to use the command prompt, strangely it opens and closes by itself each time i open netbeans ide, and then opens the application itself and works just fine. I am curious to know why this happens. I've tried searching and asking some but could get an answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: when did you download the netbeans and what's the version ?

Comment: @ChannaJayamuni i downloaded it a few days back, it's NetBeans IDE 8.0.2

Answer (score 0):

On which platform? It sounds like it's started via a shell script launcher (.sh / .cmd file), so the shell ("command prompt") is launched to run the launcher, and then the launcher script starts Netbeans...

Comment: On Windows 8.1. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Windows:

`NetBeans.exe` is a 32bit application, but if you are using a 64bit JDK, the 32bit exe closes itself (because a 32bit executable cannot load a 64bit JVM) and then launches `NetBeans64.exe` - I think this closing and re-starting is the reason for the command line window to show up briefly.

If you start `NetBeans64.exe` directly, then this doesn't happen.

Comment: Yes, i am using Windows, but i don't quite understand this. I downloaded the java SE and netbeans cobundle meant for 64bit OS, so both JDK and NetBeans, i am assuming would be 64bit application right?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Netbeans 8.0.2 on windows where commands were opening separate cmd windows.
Resolved this way:

1. Right-click on the shortcut for Netbeans or the exe (Launcher).
2. Click Run as administrator

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to right click on the icon and go to its properties. Copy the value in the `Target` field. Paste it into a command prompt and run it manually. This time the command prompt should not close and you can see for yourself what the error is.